# How to install older version on carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios, carthage

I need to have carthage for running Appium tests.
While Appium community is still working on supporting XCode9.2, we need to rely on XCode 8.3.3
OS: MacOS High Sierria
XCode version: XCode 8.3.3
Java: 1.9

But when I run command brew install carthage, I am getting below error:

```
Error: Your Xcode (8.3.3) is too outdated.
```

Please refer below link, which implies that- XCode9 support for Appium is not yet rolled-out

[https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/639][1]

Kindly suggest work around in meanwhile.
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) First of all be sure to remove everything:

`brew uninstall --force carthage`

2) Then search the commit that you like from here:

`https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?p=2&q=carthage&type=Commits&utf8=✓`

3) in your case might be this:

`https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/f74d9ba598c9843552450abeb382cacd0e71d4c0`

the one related to Carthage v0.24, which should be compatible with your requirement of working with Xcode 8.3.3.

4) then get the commit identifier `f74d9ba598c9843552450abeb382cacd0e71d4c0` and run:

`brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/raw/f74d9ba598c9843552450abeb382cacd0e71d4c0/Formula/carthage.rb`

Comment: Still I am getting error that - 'Your XCode (8.3.3) is too outdated.' I tried going back till Apr 2016 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/26c95ceebef5ec02c208ba6404655d59cd06d27a

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but was unable to use `brew install`. I kept getting a 404 error when trying to do it.

To get an old version I cloned the Carthage project from the repo, changed my working copy to the specified version tag I needed and ran `make install`. This worked :D